# GraphQL+React+Apollo:Unable to fetch data from server to client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

When i query server with the following:-

```js
query{
  counterparty {
    name
  }
}
```

I get the desired output.

But when i try display the output in screen by rendering a componenet in react i get the following error:-

[image]

Following is the code in my client side:-
My App.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost";
import { ApolloProvider } from "react-apollo";
import {ExchangeRates} from "./ExchangeComponent.jsx"

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "https://localhost:5000/graphql"
}); 

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
          <div>
            <h2>My first Apollo app </h2>
            <div><ExchangeRates/></div>
          </div>
        </ApolloProvider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My ExchangeComponent:-

```js
import React from "react"
import { Query } from "react-apollo";
import gql from "graphql-tag";

export const ExchangeRates = () => (
  <Query
    query={gql`
     {
    counterparty {
     name
    }
  }
    `}
  >
    {({ loading, error, data }) => {
      if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
      if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>;

      return  <div>
            data {data}
        </div>
    
    }}
  </Query>
);
```

Comment: seems like your GQL is not running... check your GQL server if its up and running on that port

Comment: It is running,I got the perfect output from server

Comment: Hi is your local GQL running on https ?

Comment: The url is : localhost:5000/graphiql

Comment: but I see `uri: "https://localhost:5000/graphql"` - had troubles with this exacly, while `http://` was working

Comment: Then maybe something with CORS? I see that error on the preflight (`OPTIONS`) request, could you explore the request-response ? (Network tab)

Comment: Now i am getting this error:- Fetch API cannot load localhost:5000/graphql. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request

Comment: @Honza enabling cors solved my problem.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your CORS settings, as the fetch request fails on the preflight OPTION request :)